# Generation of a .cpp file

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to Visual C++ and I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 to build an application.
The application for now has to generate a .cpp file from a proprietory .cfg file. Can anyone please guide how this can be achieved. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Viren

Comment: What does the proprietary .cfg file look like? Have you considered parsing it to generate the output? Have you attempted this at all before posting here?

Comment: What does the cpp need to do? What is the .cfg file like? Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, however it sounds like you need to develop some kind of parser to read in the cfg files and translate it into some form of intermediate language or object graph, optimize it, and then output it to c++. Sounds to me like a job for a home-grown compiler.

If you aren't familar with the different phases of a compiler I would highly recommend you check out the infamous dragon book

[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1244657404&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)

Then again, if this is for an important project with a deadline you probably don't have a lot of time to spend in the world of compiler theory. Instead you might want to check out antlr. It is really useful for creating a lexar and parser for you based on grammar rules that you define from the syntax of the cfg files. You can use the antlr parser to translate the cfg files into an AST or some other form of object graph. At that point you are going to be responsible for manipulating, optimizing and outputting the c++ syntax to a new file.

I haven't read it yet but this is supposed to be an excellent book for novice and experienced antlr users

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference

plus there a plenty of antlr tutorials and examples online that I've used to help learn it. Hope that helps put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith for the links...they really helped me in understanding the working of compilers..however the problem requirement has changed and it seems that i will be writing my application in c# instead of vc++...thank you anyways for your help..